# Integrate Google input tools in java program

Tags: java, integration

I am writing a **java program** where I need to convert(**transliterate**) English words into their Hindi counterparts. I have found that [Google input tools](http://www.google.com/inputtools/) does that wonderfully. But I can't find a jar file or any such method which I can use to integrate the tool into my application. The only possible method is through online requests. Can anybody show me the offline method to take? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an offline method. It is kind of a hack. We can install Google input tools on our PC and then use `Java autobot` to write to a java `text area`. When the autobot will write the English words, the Google input tools will **intercept** the input and the actual text being written to the text area will be in Hindi.

Answer (score -2):

You  can change the font of your text field to "mangal".

Comment: Changing the font will let me write in hindi...that is already being done by Google input tools.. I have written the correct answer (according to me) below.